# Top banner removed just from home page for template Protostar

Tags: templates

Using Protostar template for website under construction www.wilddusk.com. Want to have top banner (means part of where I have uploaded logo) removed just from home page as the client insists that the same will relieve upper space to display image sliders prominently from the top.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and dirty solution, try hiding it using CSS. Protostar adds a unique class to your `<body>` tag based on the *item-id* of your current page.

Try adding this CSS:

```
body.itemid-101 header {
  display: none;
}
```

On a side note, you should be carefull when using the default Protostar template, because it's part of core Joomla and could be overwritten when you update Joomla. It's safer to make a copy of the template before modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a module on a specific page, open it via the Module Manager in the Joomla backend.

Then, under the **Menu Assignment** tab, you can select which pages it does and doesn't appear on.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this component it has many filtering options for the modules display
https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Comment: Did not check to implement your idea as the client has changed his need. Nevertheless, idea behind development of this component seems too innovative.